# How to use DynamoDB locally with Lambda

Tags: lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, dynamo-local

I think this is possible?
I have a lambda and api gateway defined in a sam template. I use sam-local to start that up. Within my lambda I would like to connect to my local dynamoDB but the lambda keeps timing out.
Code looks like:

```
let AWS = require('aws-sdk')
let dyn= new AWS.DynamoDB({ endpoint: new AWS.Endpoint("http://localhost:8000") })

function handler(event, context, callback) {
  dyn.listTables({Limit: 10}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error", err.code)
    } else {
      console.log("Table names are ", data.TableNames)
    }
  })

  let response = {
    statusCode: 200
  }
  callback(null, response)
}
```

If this code is run outside of a lambda it works fine

Comment: Try adding some more debug lines and set the lambda timeout to 300 seconds (the maximum). You should be able to narrow if down to one line.

Comment: I get the following error:

{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
  message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000',
  code: 'NetworkingError',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 8000,
  region: 'us-east-1',
  hostname: 'localhost',
  retryable: true,
  time: 2018-01-22T08:54:57.175Z }

Comment: Sounds like DynamoDB isn't running, or is running on a different port. How are you starting DynamoDB local?

Comment: java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb

which gives:

Initializing DynamoDB Local with the following configuration:
Port: 8000
InMemory: false
DbPath: null
SharedDb: true
shouldDelayTransientStatuses: false
CorsParams: *

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your DynamoDB is running on the local machine, while the SAM Local is running inside a Docker container.

If you create a Docker container for DynamoDB to run in, and have this in the same Docker network as the SAM Local container, you might have more success.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to how to get the SAM local container and the DynamoDB container to run on the same network?

Answer (score 9):

I'm doing the same thing as you. But I run locally my DynamoDB as a docker image using this command. I run this on mac:

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local
```

In your code change this:

```
endpoint: new AWS.Endpoint("http://localhost:8000")
```

to this:

```
endpoint: new AWS.Endpoint("http://docker.for.mac.localhost:8000")
```

Now lambda can connect to port and will not timed out.

Comment: So changing the endpoint to the above worked just fine for me, but I'm curious how to I ensure that the container I build my SAM service in is on the same network as the dynamodb container? I'd rather just be able to set the endpoint to `http://localhost:8000` and not have to worry about it... Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can run DynamoDB locally inside a container, but I wonder how to call it from the SAM's Lambda container (local as well)

docker run -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that may wander here how to achieve a connection with dynamodb and lambda, both running in a docker container. Started as a comment but wanted to provide examples.

- Option 1: use `docker compose` with both containers as services in docker-compose.yaml file
- Option 2: with standalone containers, manually create a local docker bridge network and connect both containers to it, here the steps to reproduce:

Create the network

```bash
sudo docker network create -d bridge [dynamodb_net]
```

Start the dynamo container, **give it a name** so your lambda will be able to to find it

```bash
sudo docker run --rm -it --network dynamodb_net -p 8000:8000 --name [dynamo-local] [dynamo-image]
```

Start your lambda container in the same fashion, you can add name to this container if you want to

```bash
sudo docker run --rm -it --network dynamodb_net -p 9000:8080 [lambda-image]
```

> NOTE: the items in `[here]` can be changed if you need to

EDIT: added ports flag